# pdf style using R objects and Rmarkdown (template style)

Tags: r, templates, object, r-markdown, paste

Let's assume I want to generate a template using R markdown. Let's also assume I have some R objects I want to paste in the Rmarkdown document.

For example, the R objects I have are:

```
dose = 10 
units = "mg"
```

If I want to write a sentence like:

The dose administered was 10 mg every 3 days.

I can use:

````
```{r}
paste("The dose administered was",dose,units,"every 3 days.")
```
````

However, the output will be:

> ## [1] The dose administered was 10 mg every 3 days.

I know I can remove the "##" using comment=NA.

Is there any way to remove also "[1]"?

Is there any other and more efficient way to insert R objects with text using R markdown?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an R chunk, use inline code

```
The dose administered was `r paste(dose, units)` every 3 days.
```

Answer (score 0):

The function cat() makes the job :)